# How to move root bone non-independently of others

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

Here is my model right now; there is a root bone at the center and 4 'arms' spanning a circular mesh:

[image]

When I use the G hotkey (in pose mode) and move it up the Z axis, *all of the bones move equally and there is no distortion in the mesh*:

[image]

When I go to edit mode and do the same movement, it looks like this:

[image]

I thought this might be because I have removed "inherit rotation and scale" from all of the 'arm' bones, but applying those has no effect.

I want to make a connection between the bones such that moving the root bone upwards keeps the outermost point of the arm bones in the same position, but moves the intermediary bones. How could I accomplish this? Thanks